# putting find in a bash_profile function

Tags: bash

I want to make bash function in my .bash_profile that basically does a `find ./ -name $1`, very simple idea, seems not to work. My tries don't print things the right way i.e.:

```
find_alias() {
     `find ./ -name $1 -print`                                                                                                                                                                           
 }
 alias ff='find_alias $1'
```

The above if I do something like `ff *.xml` I get the following one liner:

> bash: .pom.xml: Permission denied

The following after that:

```
find_alias() {
    echo -e `find ./ -name $1 -print`
}
alias ff='find_alias $1'
```

does find them all, but puts the output of that onto one massive long line, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find_alias() {
  find ./ -name $1 -print
}
```

You don't need, nor want, the backticks. That would try to execute what the `find` command returns.

Answer (score 1):

Backticks make shell treat output of what's inside them as command that should be executed. If you tried `´echo "ls"´` then it would first execute `echo "ls"`, take the output which is text `ls` and then execute it listing all files.

In your case you are executing textual result of `find ./ -name *.xml -print` which is a list of matched files. Of course it has no sense because matched file names (in most cases) are not commands.

The output you are getting means two things:

- you tried to execute script from pom.xml (like if you typed
  `./pom.xml`) - makes no sense
- you don't have execution rights for
  that file

So the simple solution for you problem, as @Mat suggested, is to remove backticks and let the output of `find` be displayed in your terminal.